# How to connect Arduino and Beaglebone

Tags: serial

I am newbie, I am afraid of doing harm and getting a burned-out Beagle Bone Black. I have soldered this [SparkFun Logic Level Converter - Bi-Directional](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12009).

I have several questions:

1. How can I check if my converter works correctly without connecting it to any board or at least only to an Arduino?
2. How should I connect all my schematic from bbb to converter and then to an Arduino. I have a bi-directional converter, BTW. Can someone draw a simple picture of how to connect?

I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method of connection is just to plug the Arduino into the BBB's USB socket.  That way there's no level conversion or anything needed - you can just open the serial port and communicate through that - what could be simpler?

You can even install avrdude on the BBB itself and upload code (HEX files) direct from the BBB, and the BBB supplies all the power.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other methods listed, which will both work, you could also use an Arduino that uses 3.3V logic and connect the serial/UART.

The Trinket: https://www.adafruit.com/products/1500?gclid=COGOxqq-z8kCFcYRHwodpL8P2A
Pro 328: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10914

Answer (score 0):

Your main concern for frying something would be when sending data from the Arduino(which uses 5V) to the Beagle (Which uses 3.3).

The Arduino *receiving* data on the Arduino RX line wouldn't be anything to worry about since you would be sending data at 3.3V from the Beagle to 5V on the Arduino( Remember that unlike RS-232, TTL serial has no carrier voltage, so current only travels over the lines when data is actually sent )

You could always hook up the Arduino side (HV/5V), program the Arduino to do

```
Serial.println("HELLO WORLD");
```

inside `void loop()`

and look for voltage being send over the RX pin on the LV side. You would still have to connect 3.3V to LV and GND to GND.